# Problem with siunitx table after package update

Tags: tables, siunitx

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
 \sisetup{
   output-decimal-marker = {.}
 }
  \begin{tabular}{
    r @{.\ } l % Right and left aligned pair of columns.
    r @{.\ } l % Right and left aligned pair of columns.
    r @{.\ } l % Right and left aligned pair of columns.
    r @{.\ } l % Right and left aligned pair of columns.
      @{}
    S[table-format = 3.3, input-symbols = {(.)}]
  }
    \toprule
     \mc{2}{Samlet placering} & \mc{2}{Placering i svømning} & \mc{2}{Placering i cykling} & \mc{3}{Placering i løb} \\
    \midrule
      1 & Anders              &  1 & Dennis                  &  1 & Anders                 &  1 & Anders   & (32.30) \\
      2 & Brian               &  2 & Brian                   &  2 & Frede                  &  2 & Gorm     & (34.08) \\
      3 & Frede               &  3 & Frederik                &  3 & Brian                  &  3 & Brian    & (34.28) \\
      4 & Dennis              &  4 & Emil                    &  4 & Emil                   &  4 & Frede    & (35.19) \\
      5 & Emil                &  5 & Henrik                  &  5 & Dennis                 &  5 & Frederik & (35.20) \\
      6 & Frederik            &  6 & Frede                   &  6 & Ivar                   &  6 & Dennis   & (35.39) \\
      7 & Gorm                &  7 & Anders                  &  7 & Henrik                 &  7 & Jens     & (35.40) \\
      8 & Henrik              &  8 & Gorm                    &  8 & Frederik               &  8 & Emil     & (35.41) \\
      9 & Ivar                &  9 & Ivar                    &  9 & Jens                   &  9 & Henrik   & (35.56) \\
     10 & Jens                & 10 & Jens                    & 10 & Gorm                   & 10 & Ivar     & (36.32) \\
    \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

After I updated [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to v3, I now get `overfull \hbox` warnings do to the last column (I suspect) and also there is now a space just after `(` in the last column. This wasn't a problem before I updated the package.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Exactly which version do you have? I've added some emulation for `input-symbols` in the latest release

Comment: @JosephWright `3.0.4`. I just updated TeX Live without any changes to the output. `:-(`

Comment: I get an overful box with v2 ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v3 I've deprecated `input-symbols`, as it's essentially the same as adding to `input-digits`. Thus I'd use `input-digits = ()0123456789`, which will work in v2 or v3.